# Navigate on pop up windows

Tags: keyboard

When I was using Windows I could navigate with tab to pop up windows for choosing 'Yes' or 'No' faster. Now on OS X  I haven't found a way. In some cases I can choose the first letter and it will be accepted. But in examples like in the picture below, there's no such a thing.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the **System preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts**.

Then you can enable **Full Keyboard Access** to **All Controls** !

[image]

Answer (score 2):

..or you can press `Control + F7` to enable this feature in a wink!